# Test Class to cover Class TeakUtility

Tags: apex

```
I have Class and I want cover the code coverage

Following is the class:

public class TaskUtility{

    public TaskUtility()
    {
    }

    public static string createTask(String Subject, Id ObjectId, String Status, String Priority, String Description, Boolean IsReminder, Integer Reminder, Id OwnerId)
    {    
    Task newTask = new Task();
    newTask.subject = Subject;
    newTask.WhatId = ObjectId;
    newTask.status = Status;
    newTask.priority = Priority;
    newTask.Description = Description ;
    newTask.isReminderSet = IsReminder;
    newTask.ReminderDateTime = system.now() + Reminder; // to b updated
    newTask.OwnerId = OwnerId;
    system.debug('newTask = '+ newTask);
    insert newTask; 

    return newTask.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Perhaps post your existing test method and we can therefore see where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the TaskUtility does specially than a normal

> new Task(subject='subject',..,)

Constructor would do

To answer your question specifically I can help you with pointers on what to check, and will let the implementation part to you

1. Id taskId = TaskUtility.createTask( all params here )
2. Task myTask = [select all params from Task where Id = :taskId]
3. system.assert(myTask.subject,passedParamSubject)

This will give you full coverage but there is nothing so complex going on here which code coverage test will help you with regression